# The inverse of the braiding $c: V \otimes W \to W \otimes V$.

Tags: representation-theory, hopf-algebras

In the [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yetter%E2%80%93Drinfeld_category#Definition). It is said that the inverse of the map 
$$
{\displaystyle c_{V,W}:V\otimes W\to W\otimes V}, \\
{\displaystyle c(v\otimes w):=v_{(-1)}{\boldsymbol {.}}w\otimes v_{(0)},}
$$ 
is 
$$
{\displaystyle c_{V,W}^{-1}(w\otimes v):=v_{(0)}\otimes S(v_{(-1)}){\boldsymbol {.}}w.} 
$$
I am trying to verify this fact as follows.
\begin{align}
& c^{-1}(c(v \otimes w)) \\
& = c^{-1}(v_{(-1)}.w \otimes v_{(0)}) \\
& = (v_{(0)})_{(0)} \otimes S( (v_{(0)})_{(-1)} ).(v_{(-1)}.w) \\
& = (v_{(0)})_{(0)} \otimes (S((v_{(0)})_{(-1)}) v_{(-1)}).w \\
& = v_{(0)} \otimes (S(v_{(-1)})v_{(-2)}).w \\
& = v_{(0)} \otimes v_{(-1)}.w.
\end{align}
But this is not $v \otimes w$. How to show that $c^{-1}$ defined above is the inverse of $c$? Thank you very much.

Edit: here $V$ is a Yetter-Drinfeld module over $H$.

Comment: @m_t_, yes, S is the antipode. $v_{(-1)}.w$ means $v_{(-1)} \in H$ acts on $w \in W$.

Comment: @m_t_, thank you for your comments. I edited the post. Here $V$ is a Yetter-Drinfeld module over $H$. Therefore $V$ is a $H$-comodule and there is a coaction $\delta(v) = v_{(-1)} \otimes v_{(0)} \in H \otimes V$, $v \in V$.

Comment: the formula for $c^{-1}$ is false, it should be $S^{-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the idea is to write
$$ c^{-1}(v_{(-1)}\cdot w \otimes v_{(0)}) = v_{(0)(0)} \otimes S(v_{(0)(-1)})\cdot(v_{(-1)}\cdot w) $$
then use the comodule condition
$$ v_{(-1)}\otimes v_{(0)(-1)}\otimes v_{(0)(0)} = v_{(-1)(1)}\otimes v_{(-1)(2)}\otimes v_{(0)} $$
to get
$$= v_{(0)} \otimes S(v_{(-1)(2)})\cdot (v_{(-1)(1)}\cdot w) = v_{(0)}\otimes (S(v_{(-1)(2)})v_{(-1)(1)})w = v_{(0)}\otimes \epsilon(v_{(-1)})w$$
using an antipode axiom, and finally
$$ = v\otimes w$$
as $v=v_{(0)}\epsilon(v_{(-1)})$ by one of the coalgebra axioms.

Comment: this is NOT the antipode axiom, it should be $S^{-1}$ in the definition of $c^{-1}$.. it's also wrong in the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yetter%E2%80%93Drinfeld_category#Braiding